# Formatting query result of Url as given string in Semantic MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, semantic-mediawiki

I want to embed the result of an ask query on a page in Semantic MediaWiki. The result column has the type Url as in `[[Has type:Url]]`. However, when embedding the code I would like to show the URL not explicitly since it is very long but as a fixed string (e.g. "Website" )as I would have typed:
[https://someURL.com Website]

I tried to set the name on the page in the property assignment itself by including:

`[[Has website::https://someURL.com | Website]]`

This is the basic structure of an example query.

```
{{#ask: [[Has website_example::true]]
 |?Has website
 |format=table
 |limit=50 |offset=0
 |link=all
 |sort=
 |order=asc
 |headers=show
 |searchlabel=... further results
 |class=sortable wikitable smwtable
}}
```

Is it possible to render the `?Has website` as a link with the text "Website" in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be have to pass through a 'template' format, and reconstruct your rows based on this template.

Example :

```
|-
! [{{{1}}} | Website]
```

then just surround your 'ask' request by table headers and footers.

Comment: Thank you, the format templates are what I need. Is it possible to apply templates only to one part of the ask query output? When I have more columns than only the website I would like to apply a template only to the website part and leave the rest as it is. I know how to do it completely within one template but I would like to concentrate only on the subpart.

Comment: Please add your question to the original question or create a new question. Template result handling is described at https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Template_format